# Evitar camelCase en una propiedad al serializar JSON

Tags: c#, json, newtonsoft

Buen día. suponiendo tengo la siguiente clase:

```
public class ChangePartNumMasterRequest
    {
        public string PartNum { get; set; }
        public bool LSubstitutePartExist { get; set; }
        public bool LIsPhantom { get; set; }
        public string UomCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "SysRowID")]
        public Guid SysRowID { get; set; }
    }
```

hago una conversión con newtonsoft.json de un objeto tipo `ChangePartNumMasterRequest`, pasándolo a notación camelCase:

```
var request = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body
                    , new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });
```

Al servicio que llamo, me dice que no estoy pasando el parámetro `SysRowID`. al revisar mi request, veo que newtonsoft le da camelCase a ese parámetro (a pesar de que se lo estoy indicando que lo debe dejar con mayúscula con el `JsonProperty`). Realicé la petición en postman dejando el parámetro como `SysRowID` y mi petición funciona. no puedo modificar el servicio de destino. ¿Puedo hacer que "ignore" el pascalCase de alguna manera sólo para ese parámetro? es decir, esperaría algo así:

```
{
  "partNum": "LI0040",
  "lSubstitutePartExist": false,
  "lIsPhantom": false,
  "SysRowID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", //este mayúscula, el resto no
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo encontré, leyendo la documentación, encontré que la propiedad `NamingStrategy` de las configuraciones pascalcase (la clase `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`), te permite especificar configuraciones del mismo. al modificar las configuraciones a las siguientes, empezó a respetar el nombre de las propiedades cuando se especifican:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
                {
                    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy { OverrideSpecifiedNames = false }
                }
            };
```

dentro de `CamelCaseNamingStrategy` tiene una propiedad `OverrideSpecifiedNames`, que es un booleano en el que, si está activo, reescribe el nombre de los parámetros aunque estén especificados. si se desactiva, cuando tú especifiques un parámetro, se respetará tal cual y no intentará serializarlo.
[Documentación de `CamelCaseNamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCaseNamingStrategy.htm)

¡Saludos!